# why is the code inside run showing error

Tags: java, multithreading, nio

I am trying to iterate through a path to get the file names inside the run(). But the anonymous class idea doesn't seem to work. Can any one tell me why??

```
public void run() {

        //error here : walkFileTree cannot be  resolved or is not a field
        paths= Files.walkFileTree(paths, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path> visitor {


            public final FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs)
                     throws IOException
                 {

                     return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
                 }

        });
```

the error still persists in BasicFileAttributes. It says that it cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: what's the error? We aren't compilers, and it will save us (and you) time if you post the error.

Comment: @elyashiv...walkFileTree cannot be a resolved field or type.

Comment: Q: why is the code inside run showing error?  A: Please update your question with the exact error message.

Comment: @paulsm4...done. please don't down vote.

Comment: editing has been done. Please have a look now.

Comment: BasicFileAttributes is JDK7 class, therefore using JRE ro JDK pre 7.0 will result in this error

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEM:

Compile error: `walkFileTree cannot be a resolved field or type`

Q: Did you create a class "Files" and declare a corresponding public method "walkFileTree()"?
   If not, it won't compile.

Q: What data type is "paths"?  Where is it declared?

Please fix these issues, and post back if you still have any questions/problems.

Please be sure to post *all* the relevant code.  Or create an [SSSCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @paulsm4....i suppose i am trying to create an anonymous class and the bracket is closed at the end.

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error in your anonymous class creation.  Here is what I understand that you want from your question:

```
  public void run() throws IOException {
    paths = Files.walkFileTree(paths, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
      @Override
      public final FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs)
          throws IOException {
        Files.delete(file);
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
      }
    });
  }
```

I think the missing `throws IOException` for `run()` would have shown up after fixing the syntax error ;)

Comment: still error at BasicFileAttribute saying it cannot be resolved to a type.

Comment: You need to `import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes` as well.